# Self login in Salesforce API in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, authentication, salesforce

I am using Salesforce api and i want to login automatically(hard code user name and password). i am using REST API and here is the login code which shows login form:

```
- (void)login {
                SFOAuthCredentials *credentials = [[[SFOAuthCredentials alloc] initWithIdentifier:remoteAccessConsumerKey] autorelease];
                credentials.protocol = @"https";
                credentials.domain = OAuthLoginDomain;
                credentials.redirectUri = OAuthRedirectURI;

                self.coordinator = [[[SFOAuthCoordinator alloc] initWithCredentials:credentials] autorelease];
                self.coordinator.delegate = self;
                NSLog(@"%@",self.coordinator);
                // remove this line if we want to cache the key, and use refresh flow
                //effectively, we are saying, purge the old login and re-authenticate each time
                [self.coordinator revokeAuthentication];

                //now let's authenticate
                [self.coordinator authenticate];
            }
```

What i want, to automatically login (not ask username or password) so where i insert user name and password?

Comment: Hi, have you succeeded? Guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you done this or need code? please mention @Sukitha

Comment: can you please post a code snippet.  thank you

Comment: Oki please give me your email address i will send you.

Comment: that is sukie2@gmail.com, thanks in advance Umair

Comment: @Umair_uas It would be really helpful to post the code snipped here somewhere. I'm also looking for an example of doing this. Can you please post how you managed this?

Comment: Ohki i am posting soon INSHA ALLAH

Comment: What are passing in "OAuthLoginDomain" as I have only ClientID, Redirect URI and Secret key. Can you please help me.

Comment: I'm using the above same code to get the salesforce login screen and am getting "token" also, but I'm not getting user claims such as first name, last name, email Id etc... Can you please help me how to get it? also can you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574257/how-to-get-salesforce-logged-in-user-claims-in-ios-native-application I got stuck from last days, please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Include zkforce in your project
- Add These files in your project

> ```
> #import "ZKSforce.h"
> #import "FDCServerSwitchboard.h"
> #import "ZKLoginResult.h"
> ```

- Add this code in .m

> ```
>         NSString *username = 
>         NSString *password = 
>         NSString *token = @"amnwcg24Uu5IenCvAJM5HgRq"; 
>         NSString *passwordToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", password, token];
>         [[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] loginWithUsername:username      password:passwordToken target:self selector:@selector(loginResult:error:)];
> ```

- See result

> ```
> - (void)loginResult:(ZKLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error
> {
>     if (result && !error)
>     {
>         NSLog(@"Hey, we logged in!");
>       //[self fetchAccounts];
>     }
>     else if (error)
>     {
>         NSLog(@"An error occurred while trying to login.");
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: This is great. How did you get it working with the SFRestAPI?

Comment: @Umar_uas Can you please tell how to integrate this code with Rest Api?

Comment: Umair, the point of StackOverflow is so we can all benefit from the solutions of others.  You have done a terrible job of posting the actual solution.  You have given no link or instructions regarding the ZKSForce classes.

Answer (score 3):

The Salesforce toolkit for iOS page shows an example of it using ZKSForce which returns a token that can be used by the REST API calls, see [the document here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_iOS)

The REST API typically uses an OAuth token which saves the user from having to enter their username and password into a third party system such as yours. They enter the login once and the system refreshes the token to stay logged in (this is an oversimplified explanation). Either use OAuth which is the correct way with mobile and the REST API or use the session ID from an old style SOAP login request.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google and I found this - https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce

Haven't tried it yet though!

Comment: Please include more than just a link in your answer. If the link ever breaks the answer won't help anyone :)