# salesforce login in ios native App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, salesforce-chatter

I am quite new to iOS and i am trying to post something from my App on salesforce(like we share something on twitter). For that i want to first display the login screen if user is already not logged in and if user is logged in he can post on salesforce from  my app. Please guide me to a tutorial or some sample code. i have done a hell lot of searching on web but didn't find any good tutorial. i have already added the SDK to my project but not able to figure out how implement all this.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try salesforce-one ? Con't you do what you need with the official app ?

Comment: No. actually i am making a app in which there are certain things which the user can share and there is some other functionality as well, thats y i cant use the official app. i need to integrate salesforce into my app.

Answer (score 0):

what about this : [SalesForce on iOS login without using the SalesForce Webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843740/salesforce-on-ios-login-without-using-the-salesforce-webview?rq=1)

The post point to SFDC API for iPhone. May be you will found what you need.

Comment: But i dont want to login programmatically.I want the user to enter username and password at runtime. and i havent found any good tutorial   or guidance at it.

Comment: I have displayed salesforce login screen but now when i am putting the username and password it is giving an error that "your login attempt has failed.the username or password may be incorrect, or location or login time may be restricted. PLease contact the administrator at your company for help."  What shall i do with this??

Comment: Are you admin of your sfdc ? Did you already access sfdc from your device ?

Comment: As far as i remember (nô more à sfdc user/admin) you should ne able to see (not to updat) in your profil if you have remote mobile authorizations. Or just try to use sfdc one from Apple store: if it work you have access