# iOS native Salesforce login

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I wonder if there is any sample code for an iOS native login screen using Salesforce mobile sdk. The sample apps from Salesforce all use Salesforce standard web login page. I wanted to customise it and add more Sso buttons.

Comment: I think this might help you if you want to go custom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134102/self-login-in-salesforce-api-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

You can auth users to SFDC without using their login page.  It is just REST.

Comment: Thanks for that John. That's way it is in theory but how to leverage mobile sdk to build with minimum effect is really what I'm after.

Comment: Have you reviewed the native iOS tutorial:  https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Samples/blob/master/iOS/tutorials/NativeiOSTutorial/NativeiOSTutorial.pdf

Comment: That one looks like it's the Sdk interacting with standard login. Is there example that does it with Native screen login instead of a web view login?